# Is there a For-loop in Boost.Compute?

Tags: c++, boost-compute

I am trying to do the following:

1. Declare and initialise a `compute::vector` of size `n` with each of the element being `1^2`, `2^2`, `3^2` ... `n^2`
2. While size of vector > 1:
   a. For i = 0 to (size of vector - 1): `n[i] += n[i+1]`
   b. Remove the last element from the vector
3. Square root the remaining element in the vector.

I implemented this with Boost.Compute in this way:

```cpp
BOOST_COMPUTE_FUNCTION(double, square, (double x),
{
   return x*x;
});

uint32_t cl_benchmark(const compute::device& gpu) {
    compute::context ctx(gpu);
    compute::command_queue queue(ctx, gpu);
    //Starts measuring time from this line
    compute::vector<double> v(size, ctx);

    compute::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 1, queue);
    compute::transform(  // b^2 and c^2 in one function
        v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), square, queue
    );

    for (uint32_t temp_size = size; temp_size > 1; temp_size--) {
        compute::adjacent_difference( // b^2 + c^2
            v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), compute::plus<double>(), queue
        );
        v.erase(v.begin(), queue);
    }
    compute::transform( // sqrt(a)
        v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), compute::sqrt<double>(), queue
    );
    //Stops measuring time
}
```

Which works but upon testing it is very slow:
size 6000 time 551ms
size 7024 time 1870ms
size 8048 time 8262ms

I know that it takes time to compile kernels as well as copying data to the GPU, but the results still seem a bit off to me.
I implemented [something similar](https://github.com/TCLRainbow/PCEater/blob/main/PCEater.cpp#L145-L153) with single-core CPU processing only and it can process this algorithm with size of ~150k in 2s.

I suspect that the `for` loop is the bottleneck, where it keeps compiling new `adjacent_difference` kernels. That's why I am wondering if it can be parallelised?
To my understanding, if it no longer compiles new `adjacent_difference` for each iteration, the CPU bottleneck should be drastically reduced.

Comment: `v.erase(v.begin(), queue);` removes the first element, not the last one. I don't know whether the resulting shifting causes the slowdown, but that looks like a bug to me in any case.

Comment: @Quentin thanks for your comment. That was intended because `adjacent_difference` would always set the first element as 1, second element being the actual result of `v[0] + v[1]` etc. etc, thats why my workaround is to remove the first element per iteration instead.

Comment: Huh, I did not know that. I also took a closer look at the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/compute/doc/html/boost/compute/adjacent_difference.html) and they specifically mention that the `result` == `first` case (modifying the vector in-place) has linear rather than constant space complexity. I assume this is because the operations are parallelized and thus a temporary output vector need to be allocated.

Comment: I wonder what the behaviour would be with different but overlapping input and output ranges, but in any case I believe the solution would then be to double-buffer using two vectors, swapping which one is the input and which is the output at each iteration. You could also skip the first element produced by `adjacent_difference` by incrementing the begin iterator rather than physically removing the element and shifting the rest.

Comment: @Quentin I've implemented your 'two vectors' suggestions and it does help, however the results are even more odd: On an AMD Renoir laptop iGPU (512MB VRAM), it scored ~100k in 2s, but consuming ~4.8GB of system memory. On a GTX 1650Ti (4GB VRAM) it scored only 30k in 2s and just sipping 200MB of VRAM in total, system memory usage is around 80MB. This is really interesting. Though both cases still can't match single-core CPU

Comment: Can't the kernels be reused instead of compiled in a loop?